# How to get the access_token to call the Apex REST service from outside using the Rest Client

Tags: apex, apexrest

How to get the access_token to call the Apex REST service from outside using the Rest Client ?

I have a connected App and that gives me

```
Consumer Secret : 1180XXXXXXXXXX

Consumer Key  : MVG9d8..z.hXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

[image]

When I used below URL, I got the error:

```
https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id="3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPIzGJ5UZDuKCOqbHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"&
client_secret="11805XXXXXXXXXX"&username="UserName"&password="Password-SecurityToken"&grant_type=password
```

**when I used below, I see the error, why ???**

[image]

**Whats wrong I used with username and password ??**
**Why its saying invalid client id ?**

**Yes I tried with below as well**

```
https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id="3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPIzGJ5UZDuKCOqbH8CCGCPnmwQuRbwLZ_2f.thbqWMX82H7JRGx4
6VYyEkuwzQ9._ww5"&client_secret="1180508865211885204"&username="pXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com"&password="AgXXXXXXXX"&grant_type=password
```

Here I put my actual username and password which I used to login into the Production salesforce org. Please guide.

**::::::UPDATED POST::::**

**Now this is final URL:'** Still it says

```
https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id="3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPIzGJ5UZDuKCOqbH8CCGCPnmwQuRbwLZ_2f.thbqWM
    X82H7JRGx46VYyEkuwzQ9._ww5"&client_secret="1180508865211885204"&username="pXXXXXXXX@xy.com"&
    password="testingme@1000Z9qVpytemh3Q7kPmU3pLEZFH"&grant_type=password
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add your username and password with a security token to the url variables that call for them? From your url it looks like you just have "Username" and "Password" where the variables should be.